# How to represent contravariant type parameter using bounds

Tags: scala, generics, types

Here is original trait that can be implemented easily without any problems:

```
trait ZPar[-KNV,+KV] {
  def get(i: KNV):List[KV]
}
```

Now I'm trying to emulate variances using bounds (similar to  what dotty is doing)

```
trait ZPar[KNV,KV] {
   def get[R  >: KNV](i: R):List[_<:KV]
}
```

Looks good so far. Until I'm trying to implement it:

```
object ZParImp extends ZPar[String,Int]{
  override def get(i: String):List[_<:Int] = {
    val v:String = i
    List(5)
  }
}
//ERROR: method get overrides nothing
```

Method `get` cannot be overriden like that.

Is there any way to override method `get` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do precisely what you want. All you know about `R >: String` is that `String` is an `R`, not that your `R` is a `String`. If `R` was `Any` you wouldn't expect to be able to do what you want to do.

In the contravariant example, `R` is fixed by the instance rather than the method. So this approach achieves the same thing:

```
trait ZPar[KNV, KV] {
  type R >: KNV
  def get(i: R): List[_ <: KV]
}

object ZParImp extends ZPar[String,Int] {

  type R = String

  override def get(i: R): List[_ <: Int] = {
    val v: String = i
    List(5)
  }

}
```

But obviously that approach has its drawbacks, and may not be what you were trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

If we provide a type parameter, imitating the original, it seems to work.

```
object ZParImp extends ZPar[String,Int]{
  override def get[S >: String](i: S):List[_<:Int] = {
    val v :S = "blah"  // <--it's a String
    List(5)
  }
}
```

Comment: the problem here is that I can't use val `i` as a String inside method's body. There is no such problems with covariance. This line:  `val v:String = i` will not compile even if we know exactly that `i` is a `String`. So `val v :S` is not a `String` but something above the string.

Comment: You're right. `i` is easily `String`-able but not a true `String`. Hmmm.